# how to create a filtering search box in excel with radio buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a search text box that filters data in excel. I have 3 columns of data. Car make, model, and color are the columns. I have radio buttons that when selected I want the search button to search based on that column data. For example, if i have the color radio button selected and search "white" I want the results to return all cars that are white. I need the VBA code for excel. Thanks
this is the code I have so far. but it only works with one of the radio buttons, when I change to ad different radio button selection it returns nothing.

Here is the screenshot of the excel sheet

[image]

```
Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim SearchString As String
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

'Load Sheet into A Variable
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  Set DataRange = sht.Range("A3:F92") 'Cell Range
  'Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  'mySearch = sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
  mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("txtSearch").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
  'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

'Determine if user is searching for number or text
  If IsNumeric(mySearch) = True Then
    SearchString = "=" & mySearch
  Else
    SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"
  End If

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
    If myButton.Value = 1 Then
      ButtonName = myButton.Text
      Exit For
    End If
  Next myButton

'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filter Data
  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:=SearchString, _
    Operator:=xlAnd

'Clear Search Field
  'sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
  sht.OLEObjects("txtSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
  MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
    vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"

End Sub
```

Comment: "*I need the VBA code for excel*" - Awesome! Give it a shot! If you can't figure it out or having trouble please come back and show us whats going wrong and we'll do the best we can to help! Unfortunately we aren't a coding service! Please refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yeah i added my trial code @Maldred

Comment: was going to say pivot table or autofilter.  Have you recorded a macro on selecting the field based on value yet?

Comment: No, but for strange reason the code I posted is functional, I restarted excel and started working WOLA!