# How to convert a Filter to work as a radio button in Pivot Tabel Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have created a Pivot Table which has a filter on a column. Image given below:

[image]

I want this to work like a radio button. Only one option should be selected at a time. And I also want "All" filter and "Select Multiple Items" checkbox to be removed. 
I have no knowledge about coding in Excel. I need layman explanation of doing this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried?
A quick search gave this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101010/how-to-create-a-filtering-search-box-in-excel-with-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you about removing filters

If the sheet already has a filter on it then:

```
Sub AutoFilter_Remove()
  Cells.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Or you could code it this way:

```
Sub AutoFilter_Remove()
  If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData  
End Sub
```

Hope that helps!